# The Functional Determinants in Peskin and Schroeder (Eq.9.77)

Tags: mathematics, complex-numbers, linear-algebra, software, functional-determinants

I'm working on the Eq.9.77 in Peskin (page 304):

> To demonstrate this, we need only apply standard identities from linear algebra.  First notice that, if a matrix $B$ has eigenvalues $b_i ,$ we can write its determinant as
> $$
> \det{B}
> ~=~ \prod_{i}{b_i}
> ~~= \exp{\left[ \sum_{i}{\log{b_i}} \right]}
> ~=~ \exp{\left[ \operatorname{Tr}{\left(\log{B}\right)} \right]}
> \,,
> \tag{9.77}
> $$
> where the logarithm of a matrix is defined by its power series.

However, I test the identity and find it doesn't work.

[image]

For $B=\{\{3, -2, 4\}, \{-2, 6, 2\}, \{4, 2, 3\}\} ,$ the left-hand side of the Eq.(9.77) is -98, and the right is 54.

Why does this happen? What are the conditions for this identity to be true? How to prove it?

Comment: @Nat Sorry? I don't understand, it is just Mathematica 12.0.

Comment: @Nat Oh, this is not the OCR, it is Chinese question mark. I forgot to close the Chinese input software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Mathematica here [evaluates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B+%7B%7B3%2C-2%2C4%7D%2C%7B-2%2C6%2C2%7D%2C%7B4%2C2%2C3%7D%7D%5D) ${\rm Log}[\text{matrix}]$ by taking ${\rm Log}$ of each matrix element, which is not the correct mathematical definition of the [complex natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) of a matrix.

Comment: Use [`MatrixLog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixLog.html) instead.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: [Great](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Exp%5BTr%5BMatrixLog%5B+%7B%7B3%2C-2%2C4%7D%2C%7B-2%2C6%2C2%7D%2C%7B4%2C2%2C3%7D%7D%5D%5D%5D), thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, since we use the $\ln$ operation, none of the eigenvalues may be negative or 0.

It's fairly trivial to prove that this must hold:
\begin{align}
\det(B) &= b_1...b_n \\
&= e^{\ln(b_1)}...e^{\ln(b_n)} \\
&= \exp(\sum_i \ln(b_i)) \\
&= \exp[Tr(\ln B)]
\end{align}

Since we can find the eigenvalues of $B$, we can also diagonalise it with the property that
\begin{equation}
\ln[diag(b_1,...,b_n)] = diag(\ln b_1,..., \ln b_n)
\end{equation}
Also remember that diagonalisation doesn't alter the trace due to the cyclic property: let $S$ be the matrix that diagonalises $B$ then
\begin{equation}
Tr(B') = Tr(S^{-1}BS) = Tr(B S S^{-1}) = Tr(B)
\end{equation}
The same holds for the $\det$.
I am not familiar with your code, but I hope your $\log$ is nog the standard log with base 10, it has to be the natural one.

Comment: It is not true that you can always diagonalise your matrix B. To correctly take the log of a general matrix, you should use the Jordan decomposition. So your proof holds, but only for diagonalisable matrices.

Comment: Well, since there can be no 0 eigenvalues, otherwise the $\ln$ would be ill-defined, te determinant will never be 0. I mean, for this procedure to work you implicitly assume the matrix to be diagonalisable.

Comment: Even if all eigenvalues are non-zero, or even non-negative, it is not guaranteed that your matrix will be diagonalisable. What you can assume always is that your matrix can be put in the Jordan decomposition form. 

However I agree that usually, to ensure positivity and reality of eigenvalues, we usually take the log of (positive definite) hermitian matrices, for which this proof works.